# Correct output is not displaying on defining the ngIf in angular

Tags: angular

I am currently new to Angular, i have created a program where I'm using directive ngIF, getting the correct output but some additional Div details is showing up on screen which not supposed to be display.

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'newlearn',
    template:`
        <div *ngIf="courses.length > 0">
            List of Courses
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="courses.length == 0">
            Not yet
        </div>

})
export class NewlearnComponent 
{
    courses=[1,2];
}
```

Expected Result : List of courses

Actual Result :
List of courses
List of courses
not yet

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqplgy)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to use  tag so you can  ternary operator as follows

```
{{courses.length > 0?' List of Courses':' Not yet'}}
```

or you use ng-template

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="courses.length > 0" [ngIfElse]="notyet">
    List of Courses
</ng-template>

<ng-template #notyet>
   Not yet
</ng-template>
```

Hope this will  help.